# button not clicking in PartialView

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages, partial-views

I have created This PartialView Named `_GreetingsSummary.cshtml`, everything is showing fine except that the button `Use` is not working.

```
<div hidden>@Model List<Helper.BoldString></div>

<div class="container mt-4" style="border:1px solid black; border-radius:6px 6px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @foreach (var text in @Model)
            {
                <b>@text.BoldLetter</b>@text.RemainingString <br>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <div hidden>@Helper.InMemoryInfoHolder.SelectedGreeting=@Model;</div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary m-2" asp-page="./Login">Use</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

here is the calling of the same:

```
 <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="text-center font-weight-bolder text-center">SELECT ONE OF THE GREETING TO CREATE YOUR CARD</div>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Greetings)
            {
                <partial name="_GreetingsSummary" model="@item" />
            }

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem that is what is HTML element do you want in "Use" case? Button or link, it's not problem in PartialView.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `<button>` tag with `<a>` tag and the button started working fine.